# Upload com Thymeleaf

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, thymeleaf

Boa tarde pessoal,
Estou com uma dificuldade, estou desenvolvendo um sistema simples, ele lê um arquivo csv e importa para uma base de dados, arrisquei usar o Thymeleaf, achei alguns tutoriais mas não consegui entender muito bem, se alguém sabe como fazer, por gentileza me dê uma luz kkk
Estava tentando fazer assim no front:

```
    <form th:action="@{/upload}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Importar">
</form>
```

e no backend:

```
@GetMapping("/upload")
public void importar(MultipartFile mf) {
    try {
        importService.montaAbastecimento(mf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao importar: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

esse é só o método que quero chamar, a classe esta anotada com @Controller

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Não entendo muito de Thymeleaf, mas se no *backend* você espera um objeto `MultipartFile`, você não deveria enviar um *multipart* também?

Comment: @nullptr o problema é esse thymeleaf template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: adicione a stacktrace a pergunta

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss então Anderson eu também não conheço muito, vi alguns exemplos assim, porém não sei exatamente com q tipo o Thymeleaf envia esses arquivos, de inicio tentei com File do java mas tambem não rolou

Comment: @nullptr eu segui a dica do amigo ali em baixo tiago, ele mudou o stack, vou voltar como tava e posto para você ver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema do seguinte jeito:

no frontend:

```
                    <form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
                    <br /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
```

no meu controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
public void importar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile mf) {
    System.out.println("Iniciando a importação do arquivo: "+mf.getOriginalFilename());
    try {
        importService.montaAbastecimento(mf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao importar: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

ai no serviço só fazer a leitura normal de um arquivo em Java usando o InputStreamReader e pegando mf.getInputStream()

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o MultipartHttpServletRequest

```
    public void upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
            MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile(request.getFileNames().next());
    }
```

Comment: Boa tarde Tiago, obrigado pela força, mas agora tive outro erro, é necessário, mudar algo no front-end tambem?

Comment: Estive pesquisando aqui um pouco sobre o erro porém não achei nada parecido: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter$ResourceUrlEncodingRequestWrapper@3620a9de

Comment: Pelo jeito você não está usando Spring junto com thymeleaf. Essa classe MultipartHttpServletRequest é do pacote spring web mvc.

Answer (score 0):

nullptr, voltei como estava, segue o stack

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "upload", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:865) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:608) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087) [thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061) [thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:63) [spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

[2m2019-06-24 17:36:28.025[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m5192[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "upload", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "upload", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:865) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:608) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:63) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]